# Facebook app for internal use

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I want to automaticaly publish content from my internal back office to my facebook page.

What i understand is that i have to create a facebook app with the rights publish_pages, publish_actions, manage_pages.

To publish this app they ask me information and test access of the app like:

> A member of our review team will test how your app uses manage_pages. Please give them detailed step-by-step instructions for how to see this permission the same way people using your app would.

I just want to push content to my page, there is nothing to test.

Is there a FULL tutorial somewhere to do what i want to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you only need `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`. `publish_actions` is for posting to the user wall. That being said, you don´t need to go through the review process if you don´t want to publish your App to other users.

So...the answer is: don´t send it in for review. It will work for everyone with a role in the App.